# What's the best way to configure shared filesystem directories? (beyond standard unix perms)

Tags: security, permissions

I have multiple users on my system. I'd like to have shared directories like music, video. pictures etc. The problems is that I want users to be able to write any new files to any directory, but not be able to delete or modify any files they don't own. With standard unix perms if you can add a file to a directory you can also delete others. I'd also like to make sure all the files in these directories are always readable by the user group.

Can I do this with POSIX ACL's? or do I need something more advanced like SELinux (or other security framework).

example of what I don't want to work.

```
su - root
mkdir /home/music
chmod 775 /home/music
chgrp users /home/music
su - user1 /home/music
touch /home/music/testfile
ll /home/music/testfile
su - user2
rm /home/music/testfile
ll /home/music
```

Comment: You are right, I deleted the wrong answer.

Comment: @fschmitt yeah you can't write to the other persons file (modify it) but that unfortunately doesn't prevent you from deleting the last reference to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want for your music/video etc. directories the same semantic as for /tmp.

For this, you could put the sticky bit on the directories. To quote from the chmod man-page:

> RESTRICTED DELETION FLAG OR STICKY BIT
>          The  restricted  deletion  flag  or  sticky  bit is a single bit, whose
>          interpretation depends on the file type.  For directories, it  prevents
>          unprivileged  users  from  removing or renaming a file in the directory
>          unless they  own  the  file  or  the  directory;  this  is  called  the
>          restricted  deletion  flag  for the directory, and is commonly found on
>          world-writable directories like /tmp.

Comment: hmm... I didn't realize that's part of what the sticky bit does... I will have to test it.

Comment: I guess I forgot that's what it's for... I think this is an adequate solution. /me -- for overthinking the issue